# Bash Parallel MySQL Dump

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql

I have a project on AWS which will eventually have over 100 client databases each estimated in the 1~2GB size. I need to do daily backups of each database via mysqldump not the standard AWS RDS daily snapshots.

In bash I loop through a list and dump each db one after the other which is likely to take a few hours. My question is

Is it adviseable to do a bash fork and dump the DBs in parallel?

Comment: To give a meaningful opinion it would be useful to know where its the filesystem you are dumping the DBs

Comment: the plan is to dump to an EFS(NFS) then move to S3 standard bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're having a file `client_db.list` that contains a list of databases name, all databases belong to one RDS instance `live-db.example.internal`

```
> cat client_db.list
client01_dbname
client02_dbname
client03_dbname
...
...
client_template
```

#### Basic solution

The solution is using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) `apt install parallel` for executing mysqldump each database in parallel

```
parallel -j2 -a client_db.list mysqldump -uroot -pXXXXXXXXX -hlive-db.example.internal \
                                         --single-transaction \
                                         --skip-lock-tables {} '>' ./backup/{.}.sql
```

#### Details

`-j2` means executing mysqldump for 2 databases at the same time, based on number of vCPU of RDS instance

The output will be:

```
ls -lh
total 3.4G
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  26M Jun  4 10:56 client01_dbname.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  26M Jun  4 10:54 client02_dbname.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  26M Jun  4 10:54 client03_dbname.sql
...
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  26M Jun  4 10:54 client_template.sql
```